# Dockerfile - Load key "/root/.ssh/id_rsa": invalid format with Build Kit

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-buildkit

I got the following error:

```
11 2.895 In Git.php line 453:
#11 2.895                                                                                
#11 2.895   Failed to execute git clone --mirror -- 'git@gitlab.com:teams/test/  
#11 2.895   bundles/test.git' '/root/.composer/cache/vcs/git-gitlab.com  
#11 2.895   -team-test.git/'                                 
#11 2.895                                                                                
#11 2.895   Cloning into bare repository '/root/.composer/cache/vcs/git-gitlab.com 
#11 2.895   -test.git'...                               
#11 2.895   Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address '1.1.1.1' to   
#11 2.895   the list of known hosts.                                                     
#11 2.895   Load key "/root/.ssh/id_rsa": invalid format                                 
#11 2.895   git@gitlab.com: Permission denied (publickey).                          
#11 2.896   fatal: Could not read from remote repository.                                
#11 2.896                                                                                
#11 2.896   Please make sure you have the correct access rights                          
#11 2.896   and the repository exists.
```

While building this test Dockerfile:

```
FROM alpine

RUN mkdir /root/.ssh/
RUN --mount=type=secret,id=ssh_key,dst=/etc/secrets/ssh_key cat /etc/secrets/ssh_key > /root/.ssh/id_rsa && chmod 400 /root/.ssh/id_rsa
RUN cat /root/.ssh/id_rsa

RUN touch /root/.ssh/known_hosts && \
      ssh-keyscan -t rsa gitlab.com >> /root/.ssh/known_hosts 

ADD source .
RUN composer install -o -n --no-scripts

RUN mkdir -pv -m 0777 var var/log var/cache var/cache/prod && \
      chmod -R 777 var && chown -R 33:33 var
```

The command that I execute for it:

```
echo -n "$BITBUCKET_SSH_KEY" > ssh_key
    DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 docker build --pull --secret id=ssh_key,src=./ssh_key -f Dockerfile-php -t ${TAG} .
```

However, I have also tried just to use env varible for docker secret with the following build command:

```
DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 docker build --pull --secret id=SSH_KEY,env=BITBUCKET_SSH_KEY -f Dockerfile-php -t${TAG} .
```

And with this changed Dockerfile layer:

```
RUN --mount=type=secret,id=SSH_KEY cat /run/secrets/SSH_KEY  > /root/.ssh/id_rsa && chmod 400 /root/.ssh/id_rsa
```

With debug layer - `RUN cat /root/.ssh/id_rsa` I see that id_rsa looks totally fine inside container, as it should look like ssh key, however the error of invalid format still persists

Comment: You are passing `BITBUCKET_SSH_KEY` as the `id`, but you are trying to clone from gitlab.com.

Comment: Part of the point of using Docker secrets is that they won't be persisted in your image.  Anyone who gets a copy of the image as you have it can `docker run --rm the-image cat /root/.ssh/id_rsa` and get your private key out.  Can you scope the `RUN --mount=type=secret` to the specific command that needs it?  Can you rearchitect the setup to not need an ssh key at all?

Comment: @LajosArpad thank you for advice, however it was changed by me, and specifically for the question, so it is not the problem